# Regex expression for detecting 2 consecutive words when first word starts with @

Tags: regex-group

I wanted to know the regex expression that detects names starting with @. For eg, in the sentence "Hi @Steve Rogers, how are you?", I want to extract out @Steve Rogers using regex. I tried using `Pattern.compile("@\\s*(\\w+)").matcher(text)`, but only "@Steve" get detected. What else should I use.??

Thanks

Comment: so how would someone detect how many spaced-words would a name have.....so i think you should switch to `PascalNaming` convention like `@SteveRogers`

Comment: `@\s*(\w+)` will match the `@` followed by optional spaces followed by a word.  If you add a space and a second work into the sequence you should be ok, for example: `@\s*(\w+\s+\w+)`  to get both names in one group or `@\s*(\w+)\s+(\w+)` to get the names in separate groups.

Comment: I changed the regex to expression. to "@(\\w+\\s\\w+). So this gives me "@Steve Rogers" if there is a name of the said pattern. Thanks @Erik

Answer (score 0):

Try `(@[\w\s]+)`

It will only capture word and spaces after the @

See example at https://regex101.com/r/4Pv9bu/1

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match an @ sign followed by a space only like `@`  and if there can be more than a single word after it:

```
(?<!\S)@\w+(?:\h+\w+)?
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `@` Match literally
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\s+\w+)?` Optionally match 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uHXAB8/1)

In Java

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)@\\w+(?:\\h+\\w+)?";
```